# WebStorm - How do 'Web Browser' Tools work?

Tags: browser, webstorm

I'm currently exploring WebStorm, part of the JetBrains IDE collection. Within **Preferences > Tools** there is a section entitled **Web Browsers** which lists of all of the modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, etc.). It is possible to enable/disable these options.

[image: WebStorm > Preferences > Tools > Web Browsers]

I cannot seem to determine what enabling/disabling these options does other than remove them from the **View > Open in Browser** select menu.

According to [this JetBrains article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/web-browsers.html), they serve the ability to preview HTML output.

What are the consequences (or perks) of disabling browsers in this section? Do these tools have any purpose other than serving as a convenient way to test your project's HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only consequence of disabling the browser is losing the ability to preview HTML files in it (via `View > Open in Browser` or using browsers bar in HTML editor)